# Disallow third-party code in Unity to access files?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Imagine I have a type of "virtual OS" framework in Unity which runs C# code that represent third-party apps the user can later launch. Would there be any way to secure that third-party code to not, say, read or write files to the local storage? A kind of sandboxed security model (maybe via each third-party app being a DLL which is given certain rights or so)?

If impossible to achieve programmatically, is there a way a project could be securely checked via a custom parser to disallow all file-access keywords ("may never include string 'IO'", with one being ok for false positives to be checked manually), or is that impossible to achieve too? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want to allow plugins in your game/app? Are you sure you want C# to be your scripting/plugin language? Also, please provide a more practical example, this is all very hypothetical and abstract - hard to reason about a solution, then.

Comment: Oh this is definitely *possible.* But way *way* out of scope of a SO question.

Comment: Andreas, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQa_mNRa_mw) provides more background into the project. Allowing third-party apps is not crucial, it is only a side idea.